# Execute function in FLWOR without using 'let'

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Let's say I create a map:

```
let $map := map:map()
```

How can I put something in that map without using `let`? Usually I have to do something like

```
let $map := map:map()
let $useless-var := map:put($map, $key, $value)
```

Seems strange that if I want to execute something and I don't care about the return value, I still have to store the result. What am I missing here?

**Note:** The important part is not map(), but the fact that I can't run a function without storing the result in some pointless variable.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to execute the functions as items in a sequence where only one item (typically, the first or last) in the sequence supplies the real value for an assignment or return, as in:

```
let $roundedX := (
    math:floor($x),
    local:function1(...),
    local:function2(...)[false()],
    ...
    )
...
return (
    local:functionA(...),
    local:functionB(...)[false()],
    ...,
    $roundedX * 10
    )
```

If the function returns a value that you want to throw away, just use a false predicate, as with two of the functions above.

Of course, this approach is only useful for functions with side effects.

Comment: If the function returns an empty sequence (like `map:put()`) you don't even need the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a FLWOR unless you need it. In my opinion FLWOR expressions are somewhat overused. I often see expressions like:

```
let $a := current-time()
return $a
```

...when it would work just as well to write:

```
current-time()
```

See also: http://blakeley.com/blogofile/2012/03/19/let-free-style-and-streaming/

Answer (score 0):

In MarkLogic 7 you can use the map constructor to generate maps recursively. I think this is probably what you want:

```
let $map := map:new( 
  (1 to 10) ! map:entry(., .)
)
```

Or you execute `map:put` as part of another sequence, or in the return statement before you return the map:

```
let $map := map:map()
let $not-useless-var := ...
return (map:put($map, string($not-useless-var), $not-useless-var), $map)
```

Comment: The point isn't really about maps - I'm just looking for a way to run a function in a FLWOR without using `let`. I updated my question to clarify a bit.

Comment: Maps are an exception, but typically, functions in XQuery don't have side effects, so if you're not going to store the result, then why would you call the function?

Comment: In XQuery, and other functional languages, everything is an expression and thus everything produces a value.  Even if that value is an empty sequence.  The language really has no notion of "just call a function".  Calling a function is an expression evaluation.  Inside a FLWOR you need to bind the result to a variable, that's the FLWOR syntax.  I use $_ as the convention for ignored variables.

Answer (score 0):

In plain XQuery (ignoring extensions like the [XQuery scripting extension](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-sx-10/)) there are no side-effects, so calling a function without using its return value is meaningless.

What you may be missing here is that `map:put()` returns a *new* map with an extra item added, it does *not* mutate the original map. So your `$useless-var` is not actually useless.

EDIT: Actually I'm not sure if MarkLogic's `map:put()` mutates the map. (If it does, that is really gross.) I was thinking of the proposed XQuery 3.1 maps (which I've used in BaseX) which definitely are immutable.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Different XQuery processors evidently all implement maps slightly differently, and in MarkLogic `map:put` does mutate the original map (and returns an empty sequence).

Comment: @wst It doesn't even have the decency to return the same map?  That is really terrible.

Comment: Yes, MarkLogic maps are directly mutable.  They're implemented as C++ data structures inside the server.  They were introduced as a performance enhancement (and are blindingly fast) but do violate the expectations of side effect-free functional programming.  They are MarkLogic-specific, not part of the XQuery standard (and pre-date XQuery 3.x by several years)  Sharp tool.  Use wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Since the focus of your question is about running a function without storing intermediate results, you might find the map operator (!) helpful:

```
local:build-sequence() ! local:do-something-to-each(.)
```

That's good for processing sequences. If you're thinking more about processing the result of something, the answer is likely in embracing the functional nature of XQuery:

```
local:produce-result(
  local:build-parameter(),
  local:retrieve-config()
)
```

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully those help.